# Editing data tables texts

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

[image]

How do i edit this fields? I'm new in this datatables, I just got this code from the internet and trying to modify it. I'm trying to fix the positions here.

This is the original template
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to setup the [language feature](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html)

Comment: Also check [Language configuration options for DataTables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language)